# How to draw attention to old github issue?

Tags: github

A year ago I have started an issue on github repository of a popular open source project. There wasn't enough data to fix it because bug was caused only by one closed source program. Recently I have stumbled upon other program that causes the bug and this one is open source. This should make it possible to fix the issue.

I have added new comment in issue providing new information, but it got no response for 10 days.
https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/6253

I wonder if maintainers see comments on  old issues in their notifications?
If they do did they discard it by accident or perhaps because in their experience most comments on old issues are useless?

Should I just edit last comment there slightly?
Will they see that?
Or what to do?

Answer (score 3):

The good news is the project is not dead. [Issues have been closed recently](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) and [PRs have been merged](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed). Someone is watching the queue. The bad news is the project has over 800 open issues at this time which means they're probably swamped.

Open Source projects are typically run by volunteers, and that looks like a low priority issue. If you want it solved, ***do everything you can do reduce the work necessary to fix the problem.*** You've already given clear instructions on how to reproduce the problem, that's a very good start.

The single best thing you can do is submit a PR with a complete patch including tests. Be sure to conform to their [developer guidelines](https://linuxmint.gitbooks.io/developer-guidelines/content/). That project does not leave PRs open long. If you can't do a complete patch, take a stab at it and submit the PR asking for help. If you don't know where to start patching, make a comment on the issue asking for help with where to start.

Basically, do the work. If you can't do the work, show a willingness to do the work.